# Resize root partition to unallocated space before

Tags: partitioning, gparted, ext4, unallocated

I need more space on my root partition running Ubuntu 17 (using Xfce session).

I do have a lot of unallocated space BEFORE.

However, when I try to resize root partition - `/dev/sdb2` , I can't add/remove a MiB...

Is this even possible?

If so, can it somehow be done **from the live system** or do I have to use live CD/USB?

[image]

There is really just Ubuntu and Xcfe session, LUBUNTU_SYSTEM is just an old label :)

Comment: You cannot resize a mounted partition so you have to use a live session. Then you can first move your / partition to the beginning of your disk and then resize. I would recommend a backup before any operation on the partitions - one never knows ...

Comment: @muclux will the system and booting remain untouched? :)

Comment: Well, as I said, better backup before. But normally all should go well, if you pay attention at what you are doing. Boot from Live DVD/USB, call gparted, move /dev/sdb2 to create an unallocated space behind it, and then resize /dev/sdb2. Don't mount your disk partitions during this operation.

Comment: @muclux Thank you, booting a linux live USB (Lubuntu Try Mode) and using GParted worked :) ... I *think* that I have read somewhere that in newer versions you can resize/move even when in the live system - is it impossible in this case because it is not just expanding to the right but also moving to the left?

Comment: You can only grow to the right while it is mounted.  Moving requires it to be unmounted.  BTRFS can even shrink while it is mounted ;)

Comment: I think that you 2 (@muclux and @psusi) should work on an answer together so this question has more clear and readable answer :) Thank you for your inputs !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partition can only be resized by modifying its end. Therefore first, you have to  move the `/` partition to the beginning of the drive, gaining some free space after the moved `/` partition. Then you can grow the `/` partition which will be done by changing its end block number to a bigger number.

These actions can both be made through GParted, called from a live system on an USB or a DVD, but not from the current system where the partition is currently mounted.